# What used with the CameraCaptureUi in windows 10 insider preview

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, preview, windows-10

How can you use the default camera app in windows 10 insider preview?

Comment: Microsoft added the Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI Type in Windows 10 SDK release 10158. For more information take a look at http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/06/30/windows-10-sdk-preview-build-10158-released/

Answer (score 0):

To initialize camera

```
Debug.WriteLine("InitializeCameraAsync");

            if (_mediaCapture == null)
            {
                // Attempt to get the front camera if one is available, but use any camera device if not
                var cameraDevice = await FindCameraDeviceByPanelAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Front);

                if (cameraDevice == null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("No camera device found!");
                    return;
                }

                // Create MediaCapture and its settings
                _mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();

                // Register for a notification when video recording has reached the maximum time and when something goes wrong
                _mediaCapture.RecordLimitationExceeded += MediaCapture_RecordLimitationExceeded;
                _mediaCapture.Failed += MediaCapture_Failed;

                var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { VideoDeviceId = cameraDevice.Id };

                // Initialize MediaCapture
                try
                {
                    await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
                    _isInitialized = true;
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("The app was denied access to the camera");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Exception when initializing MediaCapture with {0}: {1}", cameraDevice.Id, ex.ToString());
                }

                // If initialization succeeded, start the preview
                if (_isInitialized)
                {
                    // Figure out where the camera is located
                    if (cameraDevice.EnclosureLocation == null || cameraDevice.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Unknown)
                    {
                        // No information on the location of the camera, assume it's an external camera, not integrated on the device
                        _externalCamera = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Camera is fixed on the device
                        _externalCamera = false;

                        // Only mirror the preview if the camera is on the front panel
                        _mirroringPreview = (cameraDevice.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Front);
                    }
```

To Take pic use

```
await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), stream);
```

Comment: i can use the app camera in my application

Comment: If you can then thats a better option  else you will be facing many crashes since the particular package that you want to search wont be present or else you wont be able to navigate back to your app once another app opens up.
var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
   options.PreferredApplicationPackageFamilyName = "YourAppPackage"; options.PreferredApplicationDisplayName = "YourAppName";
   // in case the user has no apps installed to handle the URI
   var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri, options);

Comment: For more context on the code snippet, have a look at: http://aka.ms/2015builduniversalcamerasample